# be on a hiding to nothing

Tags: prepositions, idioms

The "to" in the idiom "be on a hiding **to** nothing" means "or." I'd like to know whether it is found in other expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "to" in this expression is the same "to" that is used to express ratios, or in particular betting odds as ratios.

> The odds on my horse winning are six-to-one. (it is expected to lose six times for every one time that it wins)

When people first said "hiding to nothing" it was a joke odds for a horse that has no chance.  It will get a hiding (be well beaten, despite receiving a "hiding" with a whip) once for every time it gets nothing (doesn't finish).

But the original literal sense is now mostly forgotten and it just means "something with no chance of success". The meaning of "to" is ignored. And indeed it's not immediately clear what "hiding" is meant to mean (it is nothing to do with being hidden, but with hide=skin in the sense of being whipped)